# double integral equal to modified Bessel function

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I need to prove that,
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} dk_x dk_z \left( \frac{\exp[i a k_x ]\exp[ib k_z]}{k^2_x + k_z ^2 + \frac{1}{l^2}}\right) =  K_0\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{l} \right)
\end{eqnarray}

$i$ is unit complex number and $K_0$ is Bessel function of second kind and one of the [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) is

\begin{eqnarray}
K_0(x) = \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\cos[x t]}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} dt
\end{eqnarray}

I have checked the relation with Mathematica for number of values of $(a,b)$.

To proceed, I used result from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration) ,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\exp[i a t]}{{p^2+t^2}} dt = \pi\frac{\exp[-pa]}{p}
\end{eqnarray}

then, integrating w.r.t $k_x$ first
\begin{eqnarray}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \left[\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}   \left( \frac{\exp[i a k_x ]}{k^2_x + k_z ^2 + \frac{1}{l^2}}\right) dk_x \right] \exp[ib k_z] dk_z = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\exp[-pa]}{p} \exp[ib k_z] dk_z 
\end{eqnarray}
where
\begin{eqnarray}
p^2 = k^2_z + \frac{1}{l^2} 
\end{eqnarray}

Now the integral turns ugly and I do not see how to obtain factor $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ together.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Hint: switch to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let we replace $k_x$ with $x$ and $k_z$ with $z$. Then we are looking for:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I &=& \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{\exp\left(i(ax+bz)\right)}{x^2+z^2+\frac{1}{l^2}}\,dx\,dz\\ &=& \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\rho}{\rho^2+\frac{1}{l^2}}\exp\left(i\left(a\rho\cos\theta+b\rho\sin\theta\right)\right)\,d\theta\,d\rho\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\rho}{\rho^2+\frac{1}{l^2}}\cdot J_0\left(\rho\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)\,d\rho.\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now we can exploit the following identities related with the (inverse) Laplace transform:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{\rho^2+\frac{1}{l^2}}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{s}{l}\right),$$
$$\mathcal{L}\left(J_0(K \rho)\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{K^2+s^2}}\tag{2}$$
to deduce:
$$ I = K_0\left(\frac{1}{l}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)\tag{3} $$
as wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack for the solution. Switching to polar coordinates I see where factor $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ comes from. I see that Laplace transforms you write are correct but how is Eq.(3) is derived from 2?

Comment: @chatur: by using $(2)$ we have that the integral can be written as $$\int \frac{\cos(s/l)}{\sqrt{K^2+s^2}}\, ds$$ that is a value for $K_0$  by your second line.